# Accessing Grandparent data from Child view

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have Django models as follows :

```
class Grandparent(model.Models):
    grandparent_name = models.CharField(max_length="100")
    grandparent_age  = models.IntegerField(default=10)

class Parent(model.Models):
    parent  = ForeignKey(Grandparent,default=1)
    parent_name = models.CharField(max_length="100")

class Child(model.Models):
    parent = ForeignKey(Parent,default=1)
    child_name = models.CharField(max_length="100")
```

I want to access Grandparent information from Child model. How do I do it using Django Rest Framework. What I want as output is : For a given child, send as response its Parent's and Grandparent's information too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use serializer in this way...

class GrandparentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     class Meta:
        model = Grandparent
        fields = ('__all__')


class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     parent = GrandparentSerializer()

     class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ('__all__')

class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   parent = ParentSerializer()
     class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('__all__')

Or provide depth =2 in child serializer to access all Foreign key details .
```

Refer link : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('__all__')
        depth = 2
```